# what is "marginal current of dissent" in the following passage?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> The Leveretts feel they need to get involved in all this because a dangerously wrongheaded consensus has taken hold among the Western media and policy elite. Blinded by cultural bias and excessive coziness with secular Iranian expatriates, the Leveretts charge, Westerners assume that the Islamic Republic is aberrant, illegitimate and temporary, and that Iran must inevitably become a secular state. These analysts therefore exaggerate the importance of what is actually an entirely **marginal current of dissent** and underestimate popular support for the Islamic Republic.

What does **marginal current of dissent** mean in the passage?

[Source: https://www.nytimes.com/...](https://www.nytimes.com/2013/03/03/books/review/going-to-tehran-by-flynt-leverett-and-hillary-mann-leverett.html)

Answer (score 3):

A "marginal current of dissent" is how the author regards the opinions of those who think the Islamic Republic is aberrant, illegitimate and temporary.

*Dissent* is difference of opinion, in this case, difference with what the author regards as the popular support for the Islamic Republic.

The word *current* means a continuing tendency:
[Merriam-Webster *current*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/current)

> noun 2 a : a tendency or course of events that is usually the result of an interplay of forces
> *currents of public opinion*

*Marginal* means not central, located at the margins or edges of something:
[Merriam-Webster *marginal*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/marginal)

> 2 C 3 : excluded from or existing outside the mainstream of society, a group, or a school of thought

I note that the title of your question uses the word *dissidents*, which i not the same as the word *dissent* used twice in the body of your question. I can't see the article since I don't subscribe to the NYT; the word "dissent* makes more sense in the quote.
A *dissident* is one who *dissents*.

Comment: Ah, Sorry, I've corrected the title, and Thanks for noting and your answer